In Dedekind domain, fractional ideals are invertible. How can we precisely compute the inverse of a given ideal in Dedekind domains
One approach I am looking at is in Dedekind domains, for any given ideal I, there exists an ideal J such that IJ is principal. We can compute this J and find the inverse of the product which is a principal ideal and combine it with J. But then problem remains to compute such a J.
Can we take the example: In $\mathbb Z[\sqrt-5]$, find the inverse of <2,$\sqrt-5>$
Please help

$I=\langle 2,\sqrt{-5}\rangle$ is the whole ring, $I=\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, as it clearly contains $-(2^2+\sqrt{-5}^2) = 1$. In particular, it's already principal, so its inverse is itself.
Perhaps you meant $I=\langle 2,1+\sqrt{-5}\rangle$? This, famously, is not a principal ideal. Here, a possible inverse of $I$ is itself $I$. Indeed, $I^2 = \langle 4,2+2\sqrt{-5},-4+2\sqrt{-5}\rangle = \langle 2\rangle$.
In number rings, this is a general phenomenon: since the ideal class group is finite, every class of ideals has finite order, meaning some power of the class is the inverse of the class. Concretely for ideals, it means that for any ideal, some power of this ideal is principal.
This at least gives you an algorithm to find inverses in number rings. I doubt that there would be a closed formula for computing the inverse in general, since computing class numbers is very hard in general.
In general Dedekind Domains, the ideal class group may be infinite, and it may free elements, i.e. there are certain ideals such that no power is principal. Here, I imagine it to be more difficult.
